# Xcode 6.3.2 - iOS - Positioning an image and text with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am currently trying to fix a ViewController I have so that it conforms to autolayout. Here is the ViewController:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1BOc.png

Here is what is looks like as run on the iPhone 6 simulator (and what I generally want it to look like across all iPhones):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0k8a.png

Here is what it looks like when I run it on the iPhone 4s simulator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/boElJ.png

Basically the image and text did not scale so it got cut off. I tried to fix this by setting constraints to the image and the labels but Xcode didn't seem to be satisfied with the constraints. Also, I feel like this is impossible because if I set a left margin constraint to the "TITLE" label, for example, it will ostensibly always be close to the image, but Xcode gives me a warning if I don't then also set right, top, and bottom constraints and the right constraint to the trailing side of the superview would make it so that the label is 200 units away from the right edge and therefore is pushed offscreen to the left.

I know there is a way but I can't figure it out. What is the proper method of approaching this?

**EDIT:**

I tried what Sujith recommended below, and couldn't make it work. The red image was being pushed completely off screen by the labels and I was getting an error that not all constraints could be satisfied simultaneously.

I'm pretty sure this happened because setting a trailing constraint on the labels causes them to be pushed to the far left. I tried to remedy this by using the constraints Sujith recommended but allowing the width of the red image to be ambiguous, moving the labels over to the far right near the edge of the superview, and extending the red image to have the same horizontal spacing between the red image and the labels, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHPav.png

This gave me this result on the iPhone 6 simulator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCTgw.png

And this result on the iPhone 4s simulator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMMdW.png

I guess this sort of works, but it isn't exactly what I was looking for. The way I see it, there are 5 areas where width can be adjusted:

1) The leading space from the red image to the superview

2) The width of the red image

3) The horizontal space between the red image and the labels

4) The width of the labels

5) The trailing space from the labels to the superview

Ideally, I want all of these 5 things to be shrunk/expanded the exact same amount when viewing in the 4s simulator or 6 simulator respectively. What is happening right now is 4 of the areas are staying exactly the same width and the width of the red image is shrinking/growing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you expose your .xib file somewhere ?

Comment: .xib? I'm writing this in swift so I don't think there is one? Sorry, I'm new to developing in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

please try this..

1. set leading space to superview for red Image
2. set top space to superview for red Image
3. set horizontal space to label
4. set top space to superview for label
5. set trailing Space to superview for label
6. set height for label

   now
7. set aspect ration for label.Width to red imageView.Width
   8 . set aspect ratio for red imageview.Width and imageview.Height